# Drop-down PHP-MySqli error

Tags: php, mysqli, dropdown

I want to make a dropdown list and i use this codes:

```
<div class="selector">
<?php
include ("connect.php");

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbnam);
?>
<div class="label">Select Name:</div>
<select name="names">
    <option value = "">---Select---</option>
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `monitoare`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value='$name'></option>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    ?>
</select>
```

as index.php

and this:

```
<?php

$dbname = 'mydabase';
$dbuser = 'myuser';
$dbpass = 'mypass';

?>
```

as connect.php and after i launch this the drop stays just with ---select--- as an option

Comment: Maybe a `typo`....you are using `$dbnam`, but in your `connect.php` file is named `$dbname`

Comment: please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and PHP will tell us. EDIT: +1 for @Hackerman comment, didn't see typo at 1st sight...

Comment: _"PHP-MySqli error"_ - So what is the error?

Comment: Another thing, you got no start `<?php` before your `$stmt = $db->prepare(...);`.

Comment: i did all of that but that doesn't work

Comment: `i did all of that but that doesn't work` doesn't help that much :/ any error ? console ?

Comment: when i run it in browser doesn't show to me any error

Comment: but in your browser console, don't you have any 500 error ?

Comment: i don't have any error

Comment: is it a problem if i programmed my database with xampp and i connect to the database with an user with global privilegies?

Comment: oups! missed something here in my example `echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";`

Comment: it gives me this before the drop down:prepare($query); $results = $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($name); $stmt->store_result(); if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { /* we have results */ ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon that you should do all of this using either MySQLi procedural or object oriented rather trying to do with prepared statements.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

You can save this in a 'connect.php' file and include it in the relevant file.

The solution to getting dropdown instead of --select-- without any errors is shown below

```
echo "<select name='names'>"

$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM monitoare";
$result =mysqli_query($db, $sql);    

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found";
}



    ?>
```

For further reference check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and also https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (corrected) example, adapt to your code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host = ""; /* your credentials here */
$user = ""; /* your credentials here */
$pwd = ""; /* your credentials here */
$db = ""; /* your credentials here */

/* connect to DBd */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pwd", "$db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error connecting to DB : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }

$query = " SELECT `name` FROM `monitoare` ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { /* we have results */

echo"<select name=\"names\"><option value=\"\">---Select---</option>";

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";
}

echo"</select>";
}
else
{ echo"[ no data ]"; }

?>
```

Comment: prepare($query); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($name); $stmt->store_result(); if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { /* we have results */ echo""; } else { echo"[ no data ]"; } ? it shows me this and at the dropdown it says $name

Comment: This code ? Did you copy/paste for testing purposes ? If not (you typed it or mixed it) there is something you missed